# How to set the currency symbol to the correct locale position ($ 20 vs 20 $) - Joda money

Tags: java, joda-money

I am using this bit of code to format my currencies (I am using joda money)

```
public static MoneyFormatter getDefaultLocaleFormatter() {
        return new MoneyFormatterBuilder()
                .appendAmountLocalized()
                .appendLiteral(" ")
                .appendCurrencySymbolLocalized()
                .toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    }
```

But as you can see, the currency symbol comes always after the amount. What I want is the correct positioning according to the given locale. Example:

Some countries may use: 20 $, others might use $20. Some might have a space in between others don't.

I did not find the solution within the library altough it seems that it should support that (It supports localizing all the rest)